Firebase sign in with email link dynamic link not working, but regular dynamic link works
I've been trying to get a passwordless email sign-in to work in iOS with Firebase, but the email link sent isn't being recognized as a dynamic link. The link in the email successfully opens my app, but isn't being recognized as a dynamic link.
main.dart
final WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding =
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);

await Firebase.initializeApp();

final PendingDynamicLinkData? initialLink =
      await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();

if (initialLink != null) {
  final Uri deepLink = initialLink.link;
  print("here");
}

FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen((pendingDynamicLinkData) {
  final Uri deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.link;
  print(deepLink);
}, onDone: () {
  print("done");
}, onError: (_) {
  print("error");
}, cancelOnError: false);

var acs = ActionCodeSettings(
    url: 'https://mysite.page.link/moke',
    dynamicLinkDomain: "mysite.page.link",
    handleCodeInApp: true,
    iOSBundleId: 'com.mysite.app',
);

await FirebaseAuth.instance.sendSignInLinkToEmail( email: email, actionCodeSettings: acs);

firebase_auth: ^5.1.2
firebase_core: ^3.2.0
firebase_dynamic_links: ^6.0.11

When I click the link https://mysite.page.link/moke, my app opens up and I am able to log the link. However, when I click the link sent to my email it doesn't log anything even though it takes me the app. I am

I was able to fix this by using the app_links package.
